# ASP.Net MVC Getting hidden field value in javasccript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, jquery-mobile, hidden

I have asked this same basic question before several times without a response, but let me try one more time, breaking it down as simple as possible.

1. I have a strongly-typed view with a hidden field on it.
2. When the view renders server-side, I am setting the value of the hidden field to a property of the model.
3. When the view renders client-side, I want to get the value of the hidden field (that was set during the server-side render) and display it in a java script alert box.

This should be a simple thing to do and yet I am unable to make it work.  I have set a break-point in the view and I can see that the hidden field is being set to the correct value.  But the javascript will not display that value.

The page/view being rendering has been gone to before.  At the time I want to display this alert, I am going back to that page and now I want to see the alert.

It is as if the page is being cached, so instead of using the new value for the hidden field it is using the old value (from the first time the page was visited).  If the DOM is being cached, how I can prevent that so that each time I visit the page I get the updated values of the page and not the cached ones?  What am I doing wrong??

```
@<input type="hidden" id="hdnShowMsg" value="@Model.ShowMsg" />

<script>
alert($('#hdnShowMsg').val());
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your script may be firing before your document is fully rendered. Use the jQuery `document ready` function.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
<script>
$(function() {
    alert($('#hdnShowMsg').val());
});
</script>
```

Also note that `document ready` is not supported within a jQuery Mobile document and you may run into problems depending on what part of the DOM you are trying to manipulate.

Use `$(document).bind("pageinit", function() {})` instead.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: I was already using the pageinit function and it did not work.  Same for using the document ready function.  I really need to figure out what is happening to cause this not to work.